# Joining layers with respective elements with PostGIS Topology

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0, topology

I'm currently using PostGIS topology extension, but I have some difficulties in understanding how the structure works:

One of the key points is the use of "layer"s: as of what I understand, features attributes should be stored in a table out of the topology's schema (the one named `topo_actualname`) and registered as a layer of that topology with `AddTopoGeometryColumn`.

However, is there a simple way to join the attributes (stored in the layer table) with the respective features (elements in the `node`, `face`, or `edge_data`)?

Now, what I do is:

```
SELECT whatever
FROM layer_tb l
     JOIN topo_topologyname.edge_data e ON (l.topo).id=edge_id;
```

But I guess the whole `layer` concept is rather useless if I have to know both the topology schema name and the layer name to get the information I want.

In fact, I think I understood that the `topo` column on the layer has enough information to know where the respective topology is, and moreover the `topology` schema stores a reference to each layer table for each topology.

Is there a short/simple/proper way to join information together? I was looking for something in the [topology extension functions](http://postgis.org/docs/Topology.html), but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: I'm a bit lost on how you're supposed to leverage topologies, too, but this might help. You can cast a `TopoGeometry` directly to a geometry: `SELECT whatever, ST_AsText(topogeom::geometry) FROM layer_tb`. The thing is that if the edges get split later on, it seems that the geometry might change as a result.

Comment: What you want are tools or data operations such as intersect, union, or merge. QGIS works with post GIS and is free and has tools like this. Features are in the layer and are joined when you merge layers based on those types of operations.

Answer (score 1):

The mapping of the attributes to the topology is not [direct](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiCreatingTopoGeometryObjects). The [relationship](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/attachment/ticket/2578/postgis_topology_data_model_explained%20%286%29.png) is something like this for a node:

```
your_topogeom -> (topogeom_id) relation table (element_id)-> (node_id) node
```

So your select statement would be more like this:

```
SELECT whatever
FROM layer_tb l
INNER JOIN relation AS r ON (((l.mytopogeom).id , (l.mytopogeom).layer_id)) = (r.topogeo_id, r.layer_id  )
INNER JOIN edge_data AS e ON (r.element_id = e.edge_id)
```